# window.resize doesn't work in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I want to reload the page if user resize the window

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

Works in Chrome, doesn't work in Firefox.

Console is free.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried this out and it worked for me.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    this.location.href = this.location.href;
});
```

If it doesn't could you elaborate more on what isn't working? Is it the refresh, or is it the event handling?